# What is algorithm that shall be added to "comon HTML" file upload server side to make it accept "AJAX"/"HTML5" files Upload?

Tags: algorithm, html, file-upload, server-side

I wonder what are changes/(steps to make) that are required to implement to server side that allows "comon HTML form" file upload to make it accept HTML5 or [AJAX](https://github.com/valums/ajax-upload) multiple files upload?

Answer (score 0):

None. Any server-side form handler that can accept at least 1 file in a form submission can be used to accept files uploaded via AJAX form submits (you just have to make multiple submits).

Now, there *are* ways to make server-side form handling more flexible, but you haven't given *any* details to work with so we have *no idea* what you are currently doing and therefor have no way to know what might need to be done to improve it.